# Partial order $\leq$ on measures $\mu$ and $\nu$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $M(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ be the vector space of finite signed measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal{A})$. Show that

$$ \mu \leq \nu \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad \mu(A)\leq \nu(A) \quad \text{for all A $\in \mathcal{A}$}$$

defines a partial order on $M(X,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{R})$.

I've read about what partial order is. I know I need to show reflexivity, antisymmetry and transivity.

For reflexivity I have that $\mu(A)\leq \mu(A)$. For antisymmetry: if $\mu(A)\leq \nu(A)$ and $\nu(A)\leq \mu(A)$, although I know there is something about the measures not being comparable (for some A, we might have $\mu(A)\leq \nu(A)$ and for some $B$ that might not hold, then they are not comparable. Finally, for transitivity: if $\mu(A)\leq \nu(A)$ and $\nu(A)\leq \lambda(A)$, then we have $\mu(A)\leq \lambda(A)$.

I don't think that is correct at all or that's what I am supposed to do.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You have proved neatly that $\leq$ is a partial order. Why do you doubt the argument?

Comment: I just haven't fully wrapped my head around the idea of partial order, but thanks!